# how i remove "index" from my website link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have been working on removing the junk from the end of my website's url, and have managed to get the .html off of all of my links, however on my homepage I cannot when accessing it from an internal link.

I have the directory index set to index.html, however any href that I have to link back to the homepage keeps the /index in the url.

```
# Sets website homepage
DirectoryIndex index.html

# mod_rewrite starts here
RewriteEngine on

# Make sure that existing directories arent changed, and wont run RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Check for file in dir w/ .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

What I had hoped would happen is any time my homepage is navigated to, the url will end simply as `.com` not as `.com/index`.  Instead, only when first navigating to the website does the url end in `.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this modified rules on top of your .htaccess file

```
# Sets website homepage
DirectoryIndex index.html

# mod_rewrite starts here
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect index
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html|htm)$ / [R=301,L]

# Make sure that existing directories arent changed, and wont run RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Check for file in dir w/ .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```